# extract tree-like data into list in R

Tags: r, json, list, api

I would like to read JSON data from the [PubChem-API](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/cid/1983/classification/JSON?classification_type=simple) on Paracetamol and extract [18.1.2 ChEBI Ontology](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/1983#section=ChEBI-Ontology) information that is stored therein (see screenshot).

**I.e.:** I want to get all the entires for each **role** (i.e. *application*, *biological role* and *chemical role*) in a list structure in R.

[image]

For this I get the data via the API and convert it into a R object (`chebi`). So far so good.

```
require(httr)
require(jsonlite)
require(data.tree)

# from JSON to R list
qurl = 'https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/cid/classification/JSON?classification_type=simple'
cid = 1983

post = POST(qurl, body = list("cid" = paste(cid, collapse = ',')))
cont_json = try(content(post, type = 'text', encoding = 'UTF-8'), silent = FALSE)

cont = fromJSON(cont_json, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)

# subset list (i.e. get CHEBI data)
cont_l = cont$Hierarchies$Hierarchy
idx = which(sapply(cont_l, function(x) x$SourceName == 'ChEBI'))
chebi = cont_l[[idx]]
```

Then from the `chebi` object I want to retrieve the information which entries each **role** (i.e. *application*, *biological role*, *chemical role*) contains.

(1) My first idea was to simply extract the Name information. However then I loose the tree-like structure of the data and don't know what belongs to which **role**.

```
ch_node = chebi$Node
sapply(ch_node, function(x) x$Information$Name)
```

(2) Secondly I saw that there's the `data.tree` package. However I don't know how to convert the `chebi` object properly.

```
chebi_tree = as.Node(ch_node) #?
```

**Question:** How can I get the **role** information from the `chebi` object into a list in R without loosing the tree-like structure?

Comment: You could turn it into a graph and walk through the structure using a graph search to get the names without losing the structure. Check out `tidygraph`. You may also be able to use it as a stepping stone to convert to `data.tree`.

Comment: Also it looks like `data.tree` objects can be constructed from JSON, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/applications.html#load-json-file